# The loop takes input once and for the second and consecutive runs it skips the inputs but print the statements given

Tags: java, arrays, loops, printing, java.util.scanner

**the following program stores values in a 2-D array a[][] and a array "a[]" using a for loop for 5 inputs.while running it takes input only once and skips the input for the following runs and takes no input from the user but it prints the statement **

```
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++) 
    {
        System.out.println("Enter the name  of Salesman = ");
        name[i]=obj.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the product quantity for " +name[i]);
        for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
        {
            a[i][j]=obj.nextInt();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo)

Comment: Are you saying that you have a variable ``a[][]`` and a variable ``a[]``? Or am I misreading the question?

Comment: @NomadMaker i wrote it wrong its names[][] and a[] both are different array

Answer (score 0):

consume the next line after reading an int

```
for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
    {
        a[i][j]=obj.nextInt();
    }
```